# Get order totals by order id without Formatting in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

How can I get all order totals without price formatting in WooCommerce?

I have tried this:

```
$order->get_order_item_totals()
```

But I get formatted prices like this:

```php
cart_subtotal = array( 
   'label' => Subtotal
   'value' => <span class="amount">$30.75</span><small class="tax_label">(ex. tax)</small>
)
total = array( 
   'label' => Total
   'value' => <span class="amount">$30.75</span>
)
```

Instead, I would like to have something like this:

```
cart_subtotal = array( 
   'label' => Subtotal
   'value' => 30.75
)
total = array( 
   'label' => Total
   'value' => 30.75
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try This

```
if ( $subtotal = (float)$order->get_subtotal()) {
$total_rows[] = array(
    'title' => 'Subtotal:',
    'value' => $subtotal
);
}
if ($cart_discount = (float)get_post_meta($order_id, '_cart_discount', true)) {
$total_rows[] = array(
    'title' => 'Discount:',
    'value' => $order->cart_discount
);
}
if ($order_shipping = (float)get_post_meta($order_id, '_order_shipping', true)) {
$total_rows[] = array(
    'title' => 'Shipping:',
    'value' => $order_shipping
);
}
if ($order_tax = (float)get_post_meta($order_id, '_order_tax', true)) {
$total_rows[] = array(
    'title' => 'tax:',
    'value' => $order_tax
);
}
if ($gettotals = (float)$order->get_total()){
$total_rows[] = array(
    'title' => 'Total:',
    'value' => $gettotals
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot It Works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Instead using **`$order->get_order_item_totals();`**, you should use:

```
// For Order Sub-Total:
$order_subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();

// For Order Total:
$order_total = $order->get_total();

$cart_subtotal = array( 
    'label' => 'Subtotal',
    'value' => $order_subtotal
);

$cart_total = array( 
     'label' => 'Total',
     'value' => $order_total
);
```

> You can use all the [function methods in Class WC_Abstract_Order](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#methods) to get different totals. 
> As each order could be different, You will need to test some of this methods first with in an **`if`** statement using inside it **`empty()`** function…

---

For order total, you could also use **`get_post_meta()`** function:

```
$order_total = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_order_total', true);
```

You could also use these others **`meta_key`** that you can find in **`wp_postmeta`** database table for an **`order ID`** with `get_post_meta()` function to make, for example, custom calculations:

```
$order_shipping =     get_post_meta( $order->id, '_order_shipping', true);
$order_discount =     get_post_meta( $order->id, '_cart_discount', true);
$order_discount_tax = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_cart_discount_tax', true);
$order_tax =          get_post_meta( $order->id, '_order_tax', true);
$order_shipping_tax = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_order_shipping_tax', true);

// this one you get it yet
$order_total =        get_post_meta( $order->id, '_order_total', true);
```

If you want to have a look to **all the data** in one **order ID** (including customer details, order items, and many more thinks…), you should use just for a view test:

```
echo var_dump( $order->get_order_item_totals() );
```

---

Reference:

- [WooCommerce Class **WC_Abstract_Order** methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#methods)
- [WordPress Code Reference - get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: thanks u so much it work but minor problem how can i get which totals exists in order . i want to list of total ,can you say how can i do this thanks

Comment: i just send order_id and want to get array of each order_totals.but in this i have to check every time for this total exists or not and also i can't get other custom total of order, i want to get all this  order_subtotal ,order_total ,order_shipping,cart_discount,order_tax,fees,coupons and other custom total of order. i think you understands my problem, sorry for english.

Comment: ya your answer too useful but now my problem still not solve.i just want to array that i said  in my question. this is work `$order->get_order_item_totals();` but the price is formated so i can't use.  want to get like this but not formated.thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120654/discussion-between-bhavik-hirani-and-loictheaztec).